# Shrinking Vue.js production file size

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking to shrink the file size of a Vue.js production build. What's the best way to find out the size of all the imports I am using? VSCode shows me when I look in each file, but it would be nice to have a visual for the entire codebase.

And is there a tool similar to [Purge CSS](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss) for Vue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you quickly want to view it at the import level, then you can use this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost

If you want to know how your entire codebase weighs in terms of filesize and you are using Webpack by chance, you could use something like this:

https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/

There are many other bundle analyzers out there. Also Purge CSS does something entirely different from your requirements.

Comment: Cheers, I use the VSCode plugin but the webpack-visualizer is what I was looking for. Kind of guessed that was the answer for the Purge idea :)